# Glassfish стартует но не показывает ничего ни на 8080, ни на 4848 портах

Tags: java, centos, glassfish

В чем может быть проблема?

CentOS 64 битная.

asadmin домены поднимает
enable-secure-admin делал

```
[root@javavps ~]# sudo lsof -Pn -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN | grep '8080\|4848'
java     1400   root  349u  IPv6 3818283652      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
java     1400   root  358u  IPv6 3818284369      0t0  TCP *:4848 (LISTEN)
```

Вот еще что выдал

```
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sendmail  377   root    4u  IPv4 3813528452      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:25 (LISTEN)
sshd      840   root    3u  IPv4 3816127270      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd      840   root    4u  IPv6 3816127277      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
httpd    1030   root    3w  IPv4 3816157910      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd    1031 apache    3u  IPv4 3816157910      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
java     1400   root  349u  IPv6 3818283652      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
java     1400   root  354u  IPv6 3818284000      0t0  TCP *:8181 (LISTEN)
java     1400   root  358u  IPv6 3818284369      0t0  TCP *:4848 (LISTEN)
java     1400   root  363u  IPv6 3818285427      0t0  TCP *:3700 (LISTEN)
java     1400   root  370u  IPv6 3818291333      0t0  TCP *:8686 (LISTEN)
java     1400   root  371u  IPv6 3818289128      0t0  TCP *:7676 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: посмотрите, слушает ли какой-нибудь процесс эти порты, например, так: `sudo lsof -Pn -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN | grep '8080\|4848'`

Comment: [root@j ~]# sudo lsof -Pn -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN | grep '8080\|4848'
java     1400   root  349u  IPv6 3818283652      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
java     1400   root  358u  IPv6 3818284369      0t0  TCP *:4848 (LISTEN)

Comment: разбитую на строки информацию лучше вставлять в вопрос, т.к. в комментариях она практически нечитаема. но насколько я могу расшифровать эту «смесь», эти порты действительно прослушиваются. и если на веб-странице нет никакой информации, значит, надо просмотреть лог-файлы. куда именно их записывает ваша программа — зависит от её настроек.

Comment: В общем не могу понять 2 вещи... 1)Все в общем стартонуло, но ничего на вебморде нет. 2)Откуда тут httpd

Comment: смотрите логи. с огромной вероятностью там есть сообщения об ошибках.

Comment: Так, короче я разобрался. Проблема была в iptables [root@javavps ~]# iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 4848 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
[root@javavps ~]# iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

Comment: оформите, пожалуйста, эту информацию в виде ответа. вполне возможно, что она поможет другим вашим коллегам, а найти её проще в ответе, нежели в комментарии.

Answer (score 3):

Значит так... 
Проблема была в том, что необходимо было открыть порты в `iptables`

```
# iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 4848 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
# iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

Разрешили порты

```
# service iptables save
```

Сохранили

```
# service iptables restart
```

Перезапустили. Теперь по адресу сервера, по порту `4848` открывается админка.